# Qt Network Access Manager JSON Get Response

Tags: c++, json, qt, http

I'm trying to pull JSON data from a URL using the Qt framework, and I've run into some issues with getting a return from the get request.  I've seen multiple questions asked regarding my issue, but none of the given solutions has solved my problem.

So I have a button that, once clicked, should execute the get request.  Here's my code.

```
//When button is pressed
void Test1::onClickCapture()
{
    qDebug() << "Capture Clicked!!";
    toPopulate();
}

//Code to execute the connection
void Test1::toPopulate() {
    qDebug() << "Populating!";

    QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QNetworkRequest request;
    QUrl url("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");
    request.setUrl(url);
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::readyRead, this, &Test1::onResult);
}

//And finally, my onResult slot
void Test1::onResult() {
    reply->deleteLater();
    if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        return;
    }
    qDebug() << "Response!";
}
```

Every time I debug the code, it never gets to my onResult slot.

I also get this error, which may be relevant.

QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::aboutToQuit() to QNativeWifiEngine::closeHandle()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code. It's working fine for me:

```
//Code to execute the connection
void MainWindow::toPopulate() {
    qDebug() << "Populating!";

    QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QNetworkRequest request;
    QUrl url("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");
    request.setUrl(url);
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)), this, SLOT(downloading(qint64,qint64)));
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onResult()));
}

void MainWindow::downloading(qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal) {
    qDebug() << "Downloading " << bytesReceived/bytesTotal*100 << " %.";
}

//And finally, my onResult slot
void MainWindow::onResult() {
    QNetworkReply* reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*> (QObject::sender());
    if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        qDebug() << "Error downloading. " << reply->errorString();
        return;
    }
    reply->deleteLater();
    qDebug() << "Response! " << reply->readAll();
}
```

Result:

```
Populating!
Downloading  -29200  %.
Downloading  100  %.
Response!  "{\n  \"userId\": 1,\n  \"id\": 1,\n  \"title\": \"sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit\",\n  \"body\": \"quia et suscipit\\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto\"\n}"
```